# url.openStream() dos not work for some webpages

Tags: java, http, url, jakarta-ee

I have a block of codes to read url page content,This code is working good for many pages but dose not work for some pages like link below:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1351421012701725?np=y

```
public static String getDataFromWebPage(String url) {
    try {
        URL urlpage = new URL(url);
        InputStream is = urlpage.openStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        br.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("*******************************");
    System.out.println("*******************************");
    System.out.println(getDataFromWebPage("http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1351421012701725?np=y"));

    System.out.println("*******************************");
    System.out.println("*******************************");

}
```

It take many time but it don't get any result ( or any exception ) in output.

Is it possible that server have some algorithm to don't response requests from robots?

how to solve this problem ?

Comment: As a side note, you should flush your buffer as close does not always perform a complete flush. I've been bit by this a few times. Better yet, use a resource block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a httpclient istead. You will find a good example here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Comment: Dear friend what I will be so grateful if you try the code upon for this link : http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0278584699000251 , Is there any security protocol to prevent robotic visit ?

Comment: I will test the site, but your solution should handle status 301 (http redirect) and cookies. Sites returns 301 and a cookie. The redirected URL checks if you got the cookie. If the cookie is missing,  you are considered to be a poor robot.